# Integral $\int \limits _0 ^\pi |\sin x + \cos x|\; dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int \limits _0 ^\pi |\sin x + \cos x|\; dx$$

If I divide integral in two parts  $\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{(\sin x + \cos x)\,dx}$ and $\int\limits_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\pi{(\sin x - \cos x)\,dx}$...I am getting $4$...Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you split at $x=\pi/2$? You have to check where $\sin x + \cos x$ becomes negative on $[0,\pi]$ and that's not at $x=\pi/2$.

You want to split the integral so that you can lose the absolute value, but in order to do so you need to know where $\sin x + \cos x \ge 0$ and where $\sin x + \cos x \le 0$ on the given interval. This comes down to solving $\sin x + \cos x = 0$ for $x \in [0,\pi]$; does that help?

I'll add a hint to solve this equation:
$$\cos x + \sin x = 0 \Leftrightarrow \sin x = -\cos x \Leftrightarrow \tan x = -1 \Leftrightarrow \cdots$$
Can you take it from here? You should end up with (b).

Comment: @ StackTD...from 0 to $pi/2$ both sin and cos are positive and later sin is positive...cos is negative....

Comment: Right, but that doesn't mean that the **sum** $\cos x + \sin x$ becomes negative at $x = \pi/2$ and that's what you're looking for... In other words: you're looking for the point where $\cos x$ becomes *as negative as* $\sin x$ is positive, so the sum becomes zero (and then negative).

Comment: @ StackTD...got it but how to solve this question please explain...

Comment: See the hint in my answer: you're looking for the point between $0$ and $\pi$ where $\cos x + \sin x$ becomes zero, so you want to solve the equation $\cos x + \sin x = 0$. Can you do that?

Comment: @ StackTD...its $3 pi/4$...

Comment: so 0 to  $3 pi/4$ ...+ve and then negative...

Comment: Correct! So split the integral at $3\pi/4$ and adjust the absolute value accordingly.

Comment: @ StackTD...thanks its answer is b ...

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt2\sin(x+\frac\pi4)$$

There is a change of sign at $x+\frac\pi4=\pi$, hence you will split there:

$$\int_0^{3\pi/4}\sqrt2\sin(x+\frac\pi4)dx+\int_{3\pi/4}^\pi-\sqrt2\sin(x+\frac\pi4)dx.$$

$$-\sqrt2\cos\pi+\sqrt2\cos\frac\pi4+\sqrt2\cos\frac{5\pi}4-\sqrt2\cos\pi=2\sqrt2.$$

Note: the integrand has period $\pi$, so that you can shift the integration interval arbitrarily. In particular, staying in the positive range of the sine,

$$\int_{-\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\sqrt2\sin(x+\frac\pi4)dx=-\sqrt2\cos\pi+\sqrt2\cos0=2\sqrt2.$$

Answer (score 1):

the function $|\sin x + \cos x| = \sqrt 2|\sin x+ \pi/4|$ is $\pi$-periodic and is symmetric about $x = \pi/2.$ use the fact $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin x \, dx = 1.$ we can use three facts together to simplify $$\int_0^\pi |\sin x + \cos x|\,dx = 2\sqrt 2\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\sin (x + \pi/4) = 2\sqrt 2. $$

Answer (score 1):

Though answers were already given, I'd like to suggest a different approach:

We see that the absolute value of $\cos(x) + \sin(x)$ is required.
Also, we are dealing with sinusoidal functions, which can be easily dealt with the square function, so:

$$
\begin{align}
\int\limits_0^\pi \lvert \cos(x) + \sin(x) \rvert &=  \\
&= \int\limits_0^\pi \sqrt{\left(\cos(x) + \sin(x) \right)^2} \\
&= \int\limits_0^\pi \sqrt{\cos^2(x) + 2  \sin(x) \cos(x) + \sin^2(x) } \\
&= \int\limits_0^\pi \sqrt{1 + 2  \sin(x) \cos(x) } \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} \text{Sinusoidal identity:} \\ 2  \sin(x) \cos(x) = \sin(2x) \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \int\limits_0^\pi \sqrt{1 + \sin(2x) } \\
\end{align}
$$
Now we should notice the function that we're dealing with (omitting the root, insignificant):
[image]
Picture was taken [from WA for `1 + sin(2x)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%20%2B%20sin%282x%29%20from%200%20to%20pi).

So we're performing a `sum` operation over the rooted sine-wave, treating all values as positive.

This is exactly like performing the same `sum` operation over the `cosine` function, with different limits - from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (due to phase shift symmetry):
$$
\begin{align}
 \int\limits_0^\pi \sqrt{1 + \sin(2x) } &= \\
 &= \int\limits_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{1 + \cos(2x) } \\
 &= \begin{bmatrix} \text{Sinusoidal identity:} \\ cos(2x) = 2 \cos^2(x) - 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
 &= \int\limits_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{1 + 2 \cos^2(x) - 1 } \\
 &= \sqrt{2} \, \int\limits_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos(x) \\
 &= 2\sqrt{2}
\end{align}
$$